# Japanese into MySQL character issue

Tags: php, mysql, character-encoding

I have a MySQL database that is almost is in English but I want to accept all foreign language character sets. Someone submitted a form in Japanese and this came in:

```
å­ã¶ã¾ã‚€ã˜è·æ¨©ã‚·ã‚«ãƒ¦å…·å´æ¨©ã›æ±ºæ—©ãƒ
```

How can I make it so all language characters are stored properly?

My MySQL DB is set up as: InnoDB, utf8mb4, utf8mb4_general_ci

I am using PDO:

```
$conn = new PDO("mysql:charset=utf8mb4;host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
```

and I am using this PHP to call the header:

```
$header_text = 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8';
header($header_text);
```

It is sending emails out correctly, just not storing the data in MySQL correctly.

Thanks

Comment: Are you using this DB with php ?

Comment: Set your DB charsets to UTF-8.  And then follow instructions here for PHP: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52558801/2430549

Comment: Please provide the Japanese, too.  Possibly it was mangled "Mojibake" multiple times; it does not respond to my simple tests.

Comment: Still not working, see updated question.