# Navbar works from my computer but not on the internet

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have 2 versions of a website i made one in english one in french. The navbar for the english version works perfectly on my computer and live on the internet so When i test the french website version on my computer the navbar works exactly as it should yet when live on the internet it's stuck at the top of the page, where as its suppose to be about 5 cms under the top. Here is the html and css code:

```
 <div id="headerNav" class="navbar-collapse collapse float--right">
                    <!-- Header Nav Links Start -->
                    <ul class="header--nav-links nav">  
                         <li class="dropdown">
                        <li><a href="index.html">Hébergement Web</a></li>                                                                                                               
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Forfaits</a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">                                  
                                <li><a href="hébergement-partagé.html">Hébergement Partagé</a></li>
                                <li><a href="wordpress.html">Hébergement WordPress</a></li>
                                <li><a href="vps-hébergement.html">Hébergement Cloud VPS</a></li>                                    
                            </ul>
                        </li>                           
                             <li><a href="domaines.html">Noms de domaines</a></li>                              
                             <li><a href="coming-soon.html">Emails</a></li> 
                             <li><a href="e-commerce.html">E-commerce</a></li>

                     <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Services</a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">                                   
                                    <a href="à propos de.html" class="dropdown-toggle" data- 
      toggle="dropdown">à propos de</a>                                       
                                        <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>  
                                        <li><a href="à propos de.html">UTD Webhosting</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="datacenter.html">Nos Datacenters</a></li>                                        
                                     </li>                                

                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                        <li><a href="coming-soon.html">Coming Soon</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="404.html">404</a></li>
                                    </ul>                                   
                                 </li>  
                             </ul>
                            <li><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
                         </ul>
                    <!-- Header Nav Links End -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <!-- Header Navbar End -->
    </header>

CSS:

.header--navbar > .container {
    position: relative;
}

.header--navbar .navbar-header {
    float: none;
}

.header--cart-btn {
    float: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 1px;
    right: 85px;
    margin-left: 0;
}

.header--navbar .navbar-toggle {
    display: block;
}

.header--navbar .navbar-collapse {
    float: none;
    display: none !important;
    position: absolute;
    left: 15px;
    right: 15px;
    max-height: -340px;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .085);
    overflow: auto !important;
}

.header--navbar .navbar-collapse.collapsing,
.header--navbar .navbar-collapse.in {
    display: block !important;
}

.header--nav-links {
    margin-top: 12px;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
    color: #222;
    background-color: #fff;
}

.header--nav-links > li {
    float: none;
}

.header--nav-links > li > a {
    display: block;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
}

.header--nav-links > .dropdown > .dropdown-menu {
    float: none;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-shadow: none;
}

.header--nav-links > .dropdown > .dropdown-menu a {
    padding-left: 30px;
    padding-right: 30px;
}

.dropdown-menu .dropdown-menu {
    float: none;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-shadow: none;
}

.dropdown-menu .dropdown-toggle:before {
    content: "\f107";
}

.header--nav-links > .dropdown > .dropdown-menu .dropdown-menu > li > a {
    padding-left: 40px;
    padding-right: 40px;
}
```

Comment: if all else is the same, I'd try to get rid of special characters and spaces in the file names; those need encoding and depending on file system, web server etc. might not be found. This might or might not be your problem, but in general, I'd try to go with simple non-special character file names as a base rule to avoid encoding issues even in cases where it should work in principle. Example "à propos de.html" -> "a_propos_de.html"

Comment: You may have an encoding issue, as Frank said.  But it may be the file itself, and its content, and not the filename.  The accented chars, if you remove them, does it work?  That'll tell you it's an encoding problem.  I have a full solution to fixing this here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52558801/2430549

Comment: @FrankHopkins i agree with your advice so i changed the characters as you suggested but it didnt work. HoldOffHunger yes i removed the accented chars from the html and changed the file names but it didnt work.

Comment: @HoldOffHunger ok i'm currently using <meta charset="utf-8">   headers so using other headers like php is a bit foreign for me. How do you install them ? Thank you

Comment: Hey, Marco Gianni: PHP headers like `header($someheader)` have equivalents across the board in all web languages, and in most system configs.  If you have wordpress, or django, or some framework, there's probably an option somewhere to turn on the charsets already, or if you have some language besides PHP (not HTML alone, unfortunately), it should have an equivalent `header` function.  Even raw Apache should have this option (in .htaccess, maybe?), so, there should 99% be some button already in your system for turning on UTF8.  Hope this helps!

Comment: @Marco Gianni : In case you are curious, here is a 12-language web-app I built, the language is interactive with the app.  I built it using the advice from my link above -- Chinese app, http://www.sortwords.com/?language=zh

Answer (score 0):

Quite a few of your tags (`ul`, `li`, also `div`) aren't closed properly in the code you posted. Browsers will try to interpret this in some way, but not necessarily the way you intended it, so this might be a cause for your problem.

I fixed those unclosed tags in the snippet below. It's hard to check your CSS, since most of the CSS rules you posted don't apply at all in the snippet, since they use the class `.header--nav-links` and similar in their selectors which isn't included in your HTML code.

Nevertheless, maybe the edited HTML code already fixes the display problem you are mentioning.

```css
.header--navbar>.container {
  position: relative;
}

.header--navbar .navbar-header {
  float: none;
}

.header--cart-btn {
  float: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1px;
  right: 85px;
  margin-left: 0;
}

.header--navbar .navbar-toggle {
  display: block;
}

.header--navbar .navbar-collapse {
  float: none;
  display: none !important;
  position: absolute;
  left: 15px;
  right: 15px;
  max-height: -340px;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .085);
  overflow: auto !important;
}

.header--navbar .navbar-collapse.collapsing,
.header--navbar .navbar-collapse.in {
  display: block !important;
}

.header--nav-links {
  margin-top: 12px;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  color: #222;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.header--nav-links>li {
  float: none;
}

.header--nav-links>li>a {
  display: block;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
}

.header--nav-links>.dropdown>.dropdown-menu {
  float: none;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.header--nav-links>.dropdown>.dropdown-menu a {
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 30px;
}

.dropdown-menu .dropdown-menu {
  float: none;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.dropdown-menu .dropdown-toggle:before {
  content: "\f107";
}

.header--nav-links>.dropdown>.dropdown-menu .dropdown-menu>li>a {
  padding-left: 40px;
  padding-right: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div id="headerNav" class="navbar-collapse collapse float--right">
  <!-- Header Nav Links Start -->
  <ul class="header--nav-links nav">
    <li class="dropdown"><a href="index.html">Hébergement Web</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Forfaits</a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="hébergement-partagé.html">Hébergement Partagé</a></li>
          <li><a href="wordpress.html">Hébergement WordPress</a></li>
          <li><a href="vps-hébergement.html">Hébergement Cloud VPS</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="domaines.html">Noms de domaines</a></li>
      <li><a href="coming-soon.html">Emails</a></li>
      <li><a href="e-commerce.html">E-commerce</a></li>

      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Services</a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <a href="à propos de.html" class="dropdown-toggle" data- toggle="dropdown">à propos de</a>
          <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
          <li><a href="à propos de.html">UTD Webhosting</a></li>
          <li><a href="datacenter.html">Nos Datacenters</a></li>
        </ul>

        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="coming-soon.html">Coming Soon</a></li>
          <li><a href="404.html">404</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
  <!-- Header Nav Links End -->
</div>
<!-- Header Navbar End -->
```

Comment: something interested happened when i used your code actually. i copied the code it didnt change anything. So i copied the code then also removed the accents as well for example hébergement-partagé and the entire navbar disappeared, i refreshed the page a few times getting the same result.

Comment: My answer wasn't intended as code that can by copied 1:1, but to show (in a reguar list with sub-lists) that the HTML closing tags need to be fixed...

Comment: Thanks i didnt see them before, i made the adjustments